# Program that reads a sequence of captions and input values (where 1 <= value <= 30) for each bar shown below, prompts are stored in two lists

Tags: python

Essentially, my question relates to setting the loops up correctly so that the output resembles this [example output for the program exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Fua.jpg). The caption input list is supposed to be right justified with the * count being multiplied by the value list input for each caption. So far I have this much sorted out for setting up the variables:

```
captionInput = input("Enter the caption (or -1 to stop): ")
valueInput = input("Enter the value for %s: " % captionInput )
captionList = []
valueList = []
```

but I am still trying to sort out the rest. I know that it will require a while loop for the caption and most likely a nested for loop with the values. The printed output as shown in the linked image is supposed to have "captioninput" ******** <= "valueinput" with each list entry added during the loop having a new line structured like the one before it until -1 is entered. I am still new to working with Python so there's a lot I have left to learn, but any assistance in figuring the rest of this out would be most welcome. Then I would know how to do similar scenarios more easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for caption, value in zip(captionList, valueList):
    print("{: >15s} {} <={:2d}".format(caption, '*'*value, value))
```

Or, if you prefer `%`-style formatting,

```py
for caption, value in zip(captionList, valueList):
    print("%15s %s <=%2d" % (caption, '*'*value, value))
```